# Merge two columns from separate dataframes with 50% randomised from each in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I must merge the 'gr' columns from the dataframe A and B together with 50% from A and 50% from B. The rows from each dataframe selected to merge must be selected randomly.

Also, I want to make sure the order of the rows from top-to-bottom is the same.

Can you please help?

Thanks you

Here is an example:

```
dataframe_A <- data.frame(row.names = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
                          gr = c("5","3","3","5","5","5","5","3","5","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","1","1","4","4","4","4","4","4"))

dataframe_B <- data.frame(row.names = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
                          gr = c("1","2","3","3","2","1","4","4","4","3","2","5","1","4","3","4","5","5","1","2","2","3","4","5","1","2","2","3","4","4","5","5","2","1","3","5","3","2","2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sample` to randomly select rows indices from both the dataframes, `sort` them so they are in the same order and `rbind` both the dataset together.

```
rbind(
  dataframe_A[sort(sample(nrow(dataframe_A), nrow(dataframe_A)/2)),,drop = FALSE],
  dataframe_B[sort(sample(nrow(dataframe_B), nrow(dataframe_B)/2)),,drop = FALSE])
```

To have non-repetitive rownames, we can do

```
inds1 <- sample(rownames(dataframe_A), nrow(dataframe_A)/2)
inds2 <- sample(setdiff(rownames(dataframe_B), inds1), nrow(dataframe_B)/2)
rbind(dataframe_A[inds1,, drop = FALSE], dataframe_B[inds2,, drop = FALSE])
```

Comment: I just tried this solution. It seems that the result order is not the same is in the two dataframes and a sample has been lost. Some of the sample names get a '1' at the end... example -- OP2645ii_d1 and OP5047___a1. I just realised those samples have been duplicated in the final list. I think sample must be set to not replace?

Comment: @KahBak `sample` has `replace = FALSE` by default so no rows are repeated.  If the rows selected have same rownames then by default R adds 1 at the end to have unique rownames.

Comment: Aha... yes, that makes sense! How can I make the randomly selected rows from either data frame not be duplicated? So basically, that selected rows from one dataframe are not present in the other dataframe?

Comment: @KahBak updated the answer to have unique sample of rows.